# What to do with my database credentials on github hosted projects?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, security, git, github

My friend and I are starting a Rails project together and hosting the repo up on Github.

What should I/we be doing with our database credentials to make sure we are not posting them publicly or clobbering each others database.yml settings?

Comment: I asked this question on Programmers.SE..   http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/12808/keeping-a-connection-string-secure-when-working-with-others

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think the best solution is to add a sample database.yml somewhere in your project and .gitignore the existing one. Someone who checks out the project will need to create the database.yml (either from scratch or the sample).

Answer (score 0):

The alternate is to use smudge/clean scripts to parse connection information. This allows you to have a complete config committed with the naughty bits concealed.